# Create Multiple Ticket Details for a event using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Please find the link mentioned [here](http://www.acruxsolutions.in/demo/uploadtest.html)

now when you click on add ticket multiple div's get generated, but when you click on advanced settings the div opens for the first div.

Comment: I also need to remove div's when not needed

Comment: on every multiple div, the advanced settings should show for that individual div

Comment: yes, but i dont have multiple ID attribute that's where i am struck

Comment: I've edited my example to show you what I mean by duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

Code sample:

```
<span class="fieldlabel"><label class="labeltext">Select Currency :</label></span>
    <span class="fieldinput"><div id="selectfield"><select>
            <option>Select Currency</option>
            <option>US DOLLAR</option>
            <option>CADIAN DOLLAR</option>                                              
    </select></div></span>

<span class="fieldlabel"><label class="labeltext">Select Ticket Format :</label></span>
    <span class="fieldinput"><div id="selectfield"><select>
            <option>Select Ticket Format</option>
                <option>QR CODE</option>
                <option>BAR CODE</option>                                               
    </select></div></span>
```

**Make Note of** `<div id="selectfield">` and `<div id="selectfield">` this is an example of duplicate id attributes.

Duplicate ids are not allowed in HTML.  Re-write your code to contain only unique id values.  If you need multiple elements to have the same "marker" you can use the class attribute which can contain multiple values and can be duplicated.

Look over the jQuery documentation, it contains very good support for selecting by class values (that is class attributes that contain a value) since this is a common technique.  It will be invaluable to you.

The logic in your code is wrong because you have multiple places where you have the same id -- this causes your duplicates and not being able to access the specific item you wish to manipulate.

Comment: Sorry Hogan if you could give a solution it would be great

Comment: @srinivas - You can't afford it.

Comment: duplicate ids are not allowed in HTML never mind JS. That's why it's an I.D. **Identification**